# Margulis normal subgroup theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

Margulis' normal subgroup theorem states that any normal subgroup of a higher rank lattice is either finite or of finite index. The obvious question is: can one classify finite normal subgroups of such lattices? (even $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ and $Sp(2n, \mathbb{Z})$ would be a good start).

Comment: Central subgroups only (if you take lattices in semi-simple connected Lie groups)? 

Comment: @Mark: That's what I thought, but was always puzzled why no one actually stated it this way, so thought that maybe I was missing something...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are the central subgroups, see http://www.mathematik.uni-regensburg.de/loeh/seminars/normal_subgroup_thm.pdf . It is proved that every non-central normal subgroup has finite index (page 7).

Comment: The fact that finite normal subgroups $N$ in lattices are central in the ambient Lie group, follows by invoking Zariski density of lattices (to the effect that $N$ is actually normal in the ambient Lie group), and then the classical fact that a discrete normal subgroup in a connected group must be central.